# The difference when using if statement true === something() vs something() === true

Tags: php

I've seen a lot of codes that places boolean in front, followed by comparison operator, and then the variable/function to test

```php
if (true === something()) {
    doStuff();
}
```

Instead of the usual

```php
if (something() === true) {
    doStuff();
}
```

Is there a real difference between them instead of personal preference?

Comment: There's no difference. It's called Yoda conditions

Comment: Note that there is another issue with this code: assuming `something()` returns a boolean, `something() === true` will be `true` when `something()` is `true` and `false` when `something()` is `false`, so *both pieces* of code are actually the same as `if (something()) { doStuff(); }`. This is a very common beginner's mistake, and generally points to the author not understanding booleans.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Only if you know for sure `something()` returns a boolean, though. Otherwise, those are not the same. It's oftentimes a good idea to use specific types (both for parameters and return values), but it's not always the case in PHP, especially standard functions.

Comment: Also, `if (something())` evaluates to false if the return value of `something()` is NULL. Any other value (except false) evaluates to true. So `if (something())` can be very misleading. In PHP I actually consider it good practice to explicitly check for a boolean. In an environment where database queries might return NULL I find such code more readable because the intent is expressed very clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The practice to put the value first for comparisons originates from a time when `==` was commonly used as a comparison operator (instead of `===` as today) and syntax highlighting and linting was not a standard. We just used simple text editors to write PHP at that time.

The "yoda style" syntax helped to avoid fatal ***typos*** in comparisons involving a variable:

```
$foo = false;
if ($foo = true) ...
```

silently results in true being assigned to variable $foo, which might not be the intention. (Also, the if is always true)

Whereas

```
$foo = false;
if (true = $foo) ...
```

results in a syntax error, saving you from a headache.